# Error - uninitialized constant Devise::IndifferentHash (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, error-handling, generator, rubymine

working in rails, and am trying the command 'rails g spree:site' as described in section 4.5 of the [Spree getting Started Guide](http://guides.spreecommerce.com/getting_started.html).  not sure what the problem is, I am running rails 3.1.1.rc2 on a windows 7 platform. The error is below.

```
    C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/spree_auth-0.40.0/lib/spree_auth.rb:17:in `a
ctivate': uninitialized constant Devise::IndifferentHash (NameError)
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.1.rc2/lib/act
ive_support/callbacks.rb:413:in `_run_prepare_callbacks'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.1.rc2/lib/act
ive_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.1.rc2/lib/action
_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:46:in `prepare!'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.1.rc2/lib/rails/ap
plication/finisher.rb:41:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.1.rc2/lib/rails/in
itializable.rb:29:in `instance_exec'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.1.rc2/lib/rails/in
itializable.rb:29:in `run'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.1.rc2/lib/rails/in
itializable.rb:54:in `block in run_initializers'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.1.rc2/lib/rails/in
itializable.rb:53:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.1.rc2/lib/rails/in
itializable.rb:53:in `run_initializers'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.1.rc2/lib/rails/ap
plication.rb:96:in `initialize!'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.1.rc2/lib/rails/ra
iltie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
        from C:/Users/Edu/RubymineProjects/myStore/config/environment.rb:5:in `<
top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.1.rc2/lib/rails/ap
plication.rb:83:in `require_environment!'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.1.rc2/lib/rails/co
mmands.rb:22:in `<top (required)>'
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with rails 3.1. The solution was to put the following lines in my GEMFILE:

```
# ===:git with the repository's url that works=== #
gem 'spree', :git => 'git://github.com/spree/spree.git'
```

This should help in your case, too.

Answer (score 0):

@jhsilva007 : Specifying this line ( gem 'spree', :git => 'git://github.com/spree/spree.git' )

definitely helped me resolving of error.

I think this line will get the latest version of the spree from github. What if I just want the particular version number of spree. I mean I don't like to get the beta version.